# Android Gradlebuild

Tags: android

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.3.1) from [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-31
>       is also present at [com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-38 value=(26.0.0-alpha1).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:34 to override.

Comment: share your manifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking (also Lint tells you so), you should not mix different versions of the support library. Even though this comes up with the manifest merger, because `android.support.VERSION` is also defined as meta data.

So to make sure this doesn't happen anymore, define version `26.0.0-alpha1` for all the support libraries. In your case especially for `appcompat`.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
```